# How to make wordpress display the same effect as a single webpage show?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

```css
kbd.plus-equals {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #999;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: visible;
}

kbd.plus-equals:after {
  content: "+\0a=";
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 6px;
}
```

```html
Please type the <kbd class="plus-equals">+=</kbd> key.
```

Open the above html ,it will display the following effct.

[image]

Now to copy all the content in my wordpress and publish it.

[image]
[image]

How to make wordpress display the same effect as a single webpage show?